# why the points I reconstructed are not in a same coordinate?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, 3d-reconstruction

I use binocular camera to reconstruct points in 3d from 2d picture,I took many pictures by binocular camera and reconstructed points(feature points have been found already),but I found that the 3d models I reconstructed are not in a same coordinate.

- I don't know the extrinsic params(by the way,I wonder how to get this params,because I got the intrinsic matrix from calibration already)
- so, I compute the E matrix(8 points algorithm) and assume project matrix P1 of camera1 is P[I|0] and calculate P2 by P1 and E
- the last step is to calculate the points in 3d by triangulation.

Code:

```
def compute_normalized_image_to_image_matrix(p1, p2, compute_essential=False):
    """ Computes the fundamental or essential matrix from corresponding points
        using the normalized 8 point algorithm.
    :input p1, p2: corresponding points with shape 3 x n
    :returns: fundamental or essential matrix with shape 3 x 3
    """
    n = p1.shape[1]
    if p2.shape[1] != n:
        raise ValueError('Number of points do not match.')

    # preprocess image coordinates
    p1n, T1 = scale_and_translate_points(p1)
    p2n, T2 = scale_and_translate_points(p2)

    # compute F or E with the coordinates
    F = compute_image_to_image_matrix(p1n, p2n, compute_essential)

    # reverse preprocessing of coordinates
    # We know that P1' E P2 = 0
    F = np.dot(T1.T, np.dot(F, T2))

    return F / F[2, 2]

def compute_fundamental_normalized(p1, p2):
    return compute_normalized_image_to_image_matrix(p1, p2)


def compute_essential_normalized(p1, p2):
    return compute_normalized_image_to_image_matrix(p1, p2, compute_essential=True)

def scale_and_translate_points(points):
    """ Scale and translate image points so that centroid of the points
        are at the origin and avg distance to the origin is equal to sqrt(2).
    :param points: array of homogenous point (3 x n)
    :returns: array of same input shape and its normalization matrix
    """
    x = points[0]
    y = points[1]
    center = points.mean(axis=1)  # mean of each row
    cx = x - center[0] # center the points
    cy = y - center[1]
    dist = np.sqrt(np.power(cx, 2) + np.power(cy, 2))
    scale = np.sqrt(2) / dist.mean()
    norm3d = np.array([
        [scale, 0, -scale * center[0]],
        [0, scale, -scale * center[1]],
        [0, 0, 1]
    ])

    return np.dot(norm3d, points), norm3d

def compute_P_from_fundamental(F):
    """ Compute the second camera matrix (assuming P1 = [I 0])
        from a fundamental matrix.
    """
    e = compute_epipole(F.T)  # left epipole
    Te = skew(e)
    return np.vstack((np.dot(Te, F.T).T, e)).T


def compute_P_from_essential(E):
    """ Compute the second camera matrix (assuming P1 = [I 0])
        from an essential matrix. E = [t]R
    :returns: list of 4 possible camera matrices.
    """
    U, S, V = np.linalg.svd(E)

    # Ensure rotation matrix are right-handed with positive determinant
    if np.linalg.det(np.dot(U, V)) < 0:
        V = -V

    # create 4 possible camera matrices (Hartley p 258)
    W = np.array([[0, -1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
    P2s = [np.vstack((np.dot(U, np.dot(W, V)).T, U[:, 2])).T,
          np.vstack((np.dot(U, np.dot(W, V)).T, -U[:, 2])).T,
          np.vstack((np.dot(U, np.dot(W.T, V)).T, U[:, 2])).T,
          np.vstack((np.dot(U, np.dot(W.T, V)).T, -U[:, 2])).T]

    return P2s

def linear_triangulation(p1, p2, m1, m2):
    """
    Linear triangulation (Hartley ch 12.2 pg 312) to find the 3D point X
    where p1 = m1 * X and p2 = m2 * X. Solve AX = 0.
    :param p1, p2: 2D points in homo. or catesian coordinates. Shape (2 x n)
    :param m1, m2: Camera matrices associated with p1 and p2. Shape (3 x 4)
    :returns: 4 x n homogenous 3d triangulated points
    """
    num_points = p1.shape[1]
    res = np.ones((4, num_points))

    for i in range(num_points):
        A = np.asarray([
            (p1[0, i] * m1[2, :] - m1[0, :]),
            (p1[1, i] * m1[2, :] - m1[1, :]),
            (p2[0, i] * m2[2, :] - m2[0, :]),
            (p2[1, i] * m2[2, :] - m2[1, :])
        ])

        _, _, V = np.linalg.svd(A)
        X = V[-1, :]
        res[:, i] = X / X[3]

    return res
```

so how can I solve this? I want all my reconstructed points to be in a same coordinate system,could you please tell me?thank you very much!

Comment: you are looking for the "registration" step of the typical 3D reconstruction pipeline. A common approach is to coarse align the single local reconstructions manually (selecting corresponding points) followed by an automatic fine-alignment with iterative closedt points (icp) algorithm. If you can make assumptions you can automate the coarse alignment step, for example in kinect fusion method the movement between two local reconstructions is so small that they are assumed to be coarse aligned already.

Comment: @Micka thanks for your suggestions,i will have a try.